# Scale usercontrol in wpf?

Tags: wpf, scale, items

i have multiple items in my usercontrol. I put everything in a grid. But now i am trying, if the resolution of my screen changes, the window scales automatically. This just doesn't work.
I already used viewbox, but not with the wanted result.
This is my usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NewWPFVragenBeheer.Maak_toets.Views.ChangeCourse"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:NewWPFVragenBeheer.Converters"
                        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="700"
            >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Vakken"
                Source="C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\Stage 26-04\stage_TFW\stage_TFW\NewWPFVragenBeheer\Data\Courses.xml"
                XPath="/Courses/Course"
           />

        <converters:RadioBoolToIntConverter x:Key="radioBoolToIntConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Viewbox Stretch="None">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="722*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="254*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Label Content="Maximale tijd:" Height="28" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,28,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"  />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,30,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=MaxTime}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />

            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,2,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=ExamName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="textBox1"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Punten:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="386,0,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23"  Text="{Binding Path=Score,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="567,2,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path= FeedbackText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,153,527,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Foreground="#FFF50D0D" />

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

this usercontrol is set in a window:

```
<Window x:Class="NewWPFVragenBeheer.MaakToetsDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:NewWPFVragenBeheer.Views"
        Title="MaakToetsDialog" 
        WindowStyle ="SingleBorderWindow"
        WindowState ="Maximized"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"        
       >


    <view:MaakToetsView />
</Window>
```

¨please someone help.

Comment: Could you describe, visually, how you want it to scale?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Grid to a fixed Width and Height, and set ViewBox.Stretch to Uniform. That should do it.

Comment: I did this. But then if i change the resolution of the screen( when using a beamer) , the grid doesn't fill up the entire screen...

Comment: @Ruben: Beamer is not word you should use outside of the language where it has been invented in (it's a silly anglicism) the 'right' word would be "projector".

Comment: @Ruben: Thats strange.. but the window is still maximized at the new resolution (and does not overlap multiple screens)? (I'd use "beamer", too, btw. Secondary language, though)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer likely is more complicated than the solution you seek, but I'll try to keep it short.

To do what you want, in my experience your best bet is to use a Grid as your primary initial element and then situate your controls within that Grid (or other Grids inside of it) and wrap the individual controls in ViewBoxes.  After that tie the UserControl SizeChanged event to a method that forces the height and width of the UserControl to maintain an appropriate ratio.

That's the best way I have found to handle it on my WPF UIs.